# writing CDATA block to NSXMLDocument file

Tags: cocoa, nsxml

How can one write CDATA block in XML file and save it to a file in cocoa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create a node containing CDATA encoded text, use method [initWithKind:options:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLNode_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002408-BCIHFHJA) on NSXMLNode.

```
NSXMLNode *cdataNode = [[NSXMLNode alloc] initWithKind:NSXMLTextKind  options:NSXMLNodeIsCDATA];
[cdataNode setStringValue:@"<some text>"];
```

And to [write xml data to a file](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/NSXML_Concepts/Articles/WritingXML.html):

```
NSData *xmlData = [xmlDoc XMLDataWithOptions:NSXMLNodePrettyPrint];
[xmlData writeToFile:fileName atomically:YES];
```